# Demo content for Alfresco Content Management

Tags: alfresco

Hello
Where can i find demo content? Something like backup's of db or live Demo with large amount of documents. I need it for testing facilities of the system and acquainted with workflow.
PS i don't need video's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for some easy way to try it and found the [BitNami Alfresco stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/alfresco), looks like a good way to start.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for bulk content, there is a tool called "[supersizemyrepo](https://github.com/lcabaceira/supersizemyrepo)" created by an Alfresco team member that allows you to quickly generate a large amount of content that is ready for bulk importing using the Alfresco Bulk Import Tool.  You can use this tool to help test and benchmark your Alfresco system.